# What are some tools / techniques to manages screenshots?

Tags: tools

Whenever I need to design a new control, I search the web for similar patterns, and take screen shots of interesting interfaces.
I later use those screen shots for reference and brainstorming.

I'm currently using Snagit 9.0, which is great for tagging and searching, but has some limitations when it comes to navigating through a series of pictures.

I wonder if there's a better tool for this specific use case?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen UX folks use [LittleSnapper](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/) to organize their screenshots.

What are the limitations you mention with SnagIt?

Comment: When I search for pics, I get a gallery view with all the matched pictures. If I click on one pf the pictures, I get it on full size, but then I can't navigate back to the gallery view, nor can I navigate back and forth between the selected pictures.

As this is a very common scenario for me, I'm getting very frustrated every time.

I would attach a screenshot but I couldn't figure out how to "snag" snagit.. :)

Comment: Thats true, in LittleSnapper you can't switch between images in the full size view. Do you have tested the similar app Voila? I'm not sure if it works there.

Comment: I have seen another app "Sparkbox"

Answer (score 0):

If you have it, Office OneNote can work well for this - just dock a notebook to the righthand side of your screen, and use the screen snipping tool as you need.

Each screenshot gets added to the notebook, together with date and time - and when you're done, you can rearrange them as you work through the ideas - remembering that OneNote isn't a linear document, so you can organise things spacially as you go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about 2 tools: 1 to grab screenshots, one to navigate through a series of pictures. What issues are you having with navigating through pictures, and could it be as simple as a file naming/saving convention to order your pictures appropriately?